# Facebook like auto complete textbox with close button in each label ( in ASP.NET)

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Can anyone provide the link to a blog/tutorial which will  help me to build  facebook like auto complete textbox with close button

These guys have implemented the one that I really wanted.

http://www.devthought.com/projects/mootools/textboxlist/

This is exactly what I need.But its paid one.

Can any one help me please...

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery Tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) is my favorite..

Answer (score 0):

the Ajax control toolkit comes with one:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Or if you implement JQuery there's the JQuery UI one:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/